# Is a custom WPF MvvmPasswordBox a bad idea?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I know that a plain text password is a bad idea, and in WPF the PasswordBox keeps a secured encrypted password, but this does not allow us to use pure MVVM.

So I attempted to make a MvvmPasswordBox while keeping security in mind.
I'm sure there are pitfalls to this, and would love to here all the bad that I have not brought into this world :).

So here is my attempt.

**MvvmPassword Xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SYSPROMA_PushServicesTestHost.Controls.MvvmPassword"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContextChanged="OnDataContextChanged">

    <TextBox    x:FieldModifier="private" Name="PasswordDisplay" 
                CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="PreviewExecuted"
                TextChanged="PasswordChanged"
                ContextMenu="{x:Null}">
    </TextBox>
</UserControl>
```

**MvvmPassword Code Behind**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SYSPROMA_PushServicesTestHost.Controls
{
    public partial class MvvmPassword
    {
        private bool _ignoreChange = false;
        public MvvmPassword()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PasswordChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_ignoreChange)
            {
                return;
            }

            var secureString = DataContext as SecureString;
            if (secureString == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var text = PasswordDisplay.Text ?? "";
            var selectionStart = PasswordDisplay.SelectionStart;
            var selectionLength = PasswordDisplay.SelectionLength;

            foreach (var change in e.Changes.OrderBy(x => x.Offset))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < change.RemovedLength; i++)
                {
                    secureString.RemoveAt(change.Offset);
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < change.AddedLength; i++)
                {
                    secureString.AppendChar(text[change.Offset + i]);
                }
            }

            _ignoreChange = true;
            PasswordDisplay.Text = new string('•', secureString.Length);
            _ignoreChange = false;

            PasswordDisplay.Select(selectionStart, selectionLength);
        }

        private void PreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy || e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var secureString = e.NewValue as SecureString;
            if (secureString == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            _ignoreChange = true;
            PasswordDisplay.Text = new string('•', secureString.Length);
            _ignoreChange = false;
        }
    }
}
```

***Removed Model***

Edited: using SecureString
Edited: removed model, do however rely on SecureString

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think you have to do encryption yourself, have a look at [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Having a model that's designed to go with your control is a code smell, imho.  Let me bind what I want to your control, whether that's a SecureString or a plain old string.

Comment: How many password boxes will your application contain? I think it's not worth the effort of implementing this just to be able to eliminate 2 lines of code behind. Use code behind in this case.